# One of the soldiers is named Joe. What is the probability that Joe has the disease if the test is positive?

Tags: probability

In an army camp, there are $3$ soldiers. For each soldier there is a probability of $0.2$ that they have a certain disease (independently from each other). The doctor wants to
determine whether any of them have it. Since the test is very expensive, he pools together blood samples from all the soldiers. If any of them, i.e., whether any one soldier or any combination of them, have the disease the test is positive with probability $0.9$. If none have it, then the test
is positive with probability $0.1$

One of the soldiers is named Joe. What is the probability that Joe has the disease if the test
is positive?

How would you solve this? I think the following is the correct, but I'm not sure.

\begin{align}
  P(\textrm{joe disease} | \textrm{test is positive})
  & =
    \frac{P(\textrm{positive}|\textrm{disease})P(\textrm{disease})}
    {P(\textrm{positive}|\textrm{disease})P(\textrm{disease}) +
    P(\textrm{positive} | \textrm{no disease})P(\textrm{no disease})} \\
  & =
   \frac{0.2 \times 0.9}{(0.2 \times .9)+(0.8 \times 0.1 \times 0.8)}= 0.7377
\end{align}

Please advise if this isn't correct.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake computing $\Pr[\text{disease}]$ and $\Pr[\text{no disease}]$. They are *not*, respectively, $0.2$ and $0.8\times 0.8$.

---

Let $S$ be the event "at least one soldier has the disease", $J$ be the event "Joe has the disease", and $T$ be the event "the test is positive."
For independence between soldiers, we get
$$
\Pr[S] = 1- (1-0.2)^3 = 1-0.8^3
$$
while $\Pr[T\mid S] = \Pr[T\mid S] = 0.9$, $\Pr[T\mid \bar{S}] = 0.1$, and $\Pr[J] = 0.2$.
By Bayes rule, we can rewrite
$$
\Pr[ J\mid T ] = \frac{\Pr[ J\cap T ]}{\Pr[ T ]}
= \frac{\Pr[ T\mid J ]\Pr[J]}{\Pr[ T \mid S ]\Pr[S]+\Pr[ T \mid \bar{S} ]\Pr[\bar{S}]}
= \frac{0.9\cdot 0.2}{0.9\cdot(1-0.8^3) + 0.1\cdot 0.8^3}
\approx 0.367
$$
where we use in the second equality the law of total probability,
$$
\Pr[ T ] =\Pr[ T \cap S ] + \Pr[ T \cap \bar{S} ] = \Pr[ T \mid S ]\Pr[S]+\Pr[ T \mid \bar{S} ]\Pr[\bar{S}]\,.
$$

Comment: I'm confused on how you computed the Pr(S). How did you transition from $1 - (1 - 0.2)^2$ => $1 - 0.8^3$

Comment: It should have been a cube everywhere (there are 3 soldiers), it was a typo. Thanks. @atn

Comment: Ok thanks! this makes a lot of sense now.

Comment: @atn Glad this helped.